# How to stop waiting for event signal once exception is raised

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some code that needs to run up a new thread to perform a lengthy task, check that the task has started, then return while the worker thread runs asynchronously. I'm new to C# threading so I don't know if I'm doing this the right way; My implementation is:

**Thread 1:**

1. Use Task.Factory.StartNew() to launch Thread 2, passing in an EventWaitHandle object which is shared between threads.
2. Call eventWaitHandle.WaitOne(); Thread 1 waits until Thread 2 signals its ready
3. Read some data from Thread 2 which is populated prior to Thread 2 signaling
4. Return data to caller; Thread 2 continues to run in the background

**Thread 2:**

1. Does some database stuff, then sets values in the shared object between Thread 1 and Thread 2
2. Call eventWaitHandle.Set() to signal to Thread 1
3. Perform long-running task

The problem I have is that Thread 2 might throw an exception and abort prior to signaling with eventWaitHandle.Set(). If this happens, Thread 1 is stuck waiting forever. As a workaround, I am calling WaitOne with a 30-second timeout, so that Thread 1 can eventually give up waiting, then read the Task.Exception object to see that it failed, and deal with the exception.

**Question:**

How can I do this properly without relying on an arbitrary timeout value? I want Thread 1 to wait for Thread 2 to signal, but stop waiting immediately if Thread 2 exits with an exception thrown.

Comment: It would be much better if you posted your actual code rather than talk about it in point form. [mcve]

Comment: Is there a reason that you use the `Task.Factory.StartNew()` method instead of the `Thread` constructor? By using an `EventWaitHandle` you imply that you want to work with low level constructs (closer to the metal). A `Task` is a higher level abstraction. You generally don't want to control tasks with low level synchronization primitives.

Comment: I wrote this code like 30 mins after reading about C# threads for the first time. I don't know what the ideal constructs are for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exception raised from async Task method are placed on the returned Task. Rased only when returned Task is awaited:

```
static async Task SomeMethod()
{
   var task = OperationWithException();
   try
   {
     await task;
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException)
   {
     // exception is correctly to caught here.
   }
}

static async Task OperationWithException()
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   // check for it
   throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to implement the producer-consumer model through two threads, without using Events, I recommend using BlockingCollection to implement your business logic. Please refer to [BlockingCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlockingCollection<long> objectPool = new BlockingCollection<long>();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                long counter = 0;
                try
                {
                    while (counter < long.MaxValue)
                    {
                        if (++counter % 1000 == 0)
                        {
                            objectPool.TryAdd(counter);
                        }
                    }
                    objectPool.CompleteAdding();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //after completeadding is called by this task, 
                    //the another task will break the foreach statement.
                    objectPool.CompleteAdding();
                }
            });


            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
               //Will block and wait until there are consumable objects.
               foreach(var obj in objectPool.GetConsumingEnumerable())
               {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj);//consume the object
               }
            });
        }
```